# JavaScript prototype issue

Tags: javascript

Currently, I'm reading 'Object-Oriented JavaScript'.
In addition, I've encountered a hiccup while carrying out an example from the book.

Below is the code sample:

```
var Dog = function() {
    this.tail = true;
};

var benji = new Dog();
var rusty = new Dog();

Dog.prototype.say = function() { return "Woof!"; };

benji.say();
rusty.say();

Dog.prototype = {
    paws: 4,
    hair: true
};
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;

var lucy = new Dog();
lucy.say();
```

Essentially, the idea is to have the following work:

1. console.log(lucy.say());
2. console.log(benji.paws);
3. The obvious - lucy.say();

etc.

Strangely enough, I've copied the example to the 'T', but to no avail.
If anyone could shed some light I'd be more than grateful.

Cheers

Comment: What "hiccup" ? What is strange?

Comment: Quoted from the book: It turns out that our old objects do not get access to the new prototype's properties; they still keep the secret link pointing to the old prototype object.The most confusing part is when you look up the prototype of the constructor:
typeof lucy.constructor.prototype.paws "undefined" 
typeof benji.constructor.prototype.paws "number"
The following would have fixed all of the unexpected behavior above:
Dog.prototype = { paws: 4, hair: true }; 
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
*Note When you overwrite the prototype, it is a good practice to reset the constructor property.

Comment: Yes, it will fix `lucy.constructor.prototype.paws` but it won't give `lucy` the `say` method.

Comment: The following works: var Dog = function() {
    this.tail = true;
    this.foo = {};
};
 
var benji = new Dog();
var rusty = new Dog();
 
Dog.prototype.say =  {
    cat: 114,
    dog: "foo"
};
 
Dog.prototype = {
    paws: 4,
    hair: true
};
 
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
 
var lucy = new Dog();
lucy.foo = benji.say;
 
console.log(benji.say.cat);
console.log(benji.say.dog);
console.log(benji.constructor.prototype.hair);
console.log(benji.constructor.prototype.paws);
 
console.log(lucy.foo.cat);
console.log(lucy.foo.dog);
console.log(lucy.hair);
console.log(lucy.paws);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing

```
Dog.prototype = {
    paws: 4,
    hair: true
};
```

you create a totally **new** prototype object (you are assigning a new object to `prototype`). The method `say()` will be not available to new `Dog` objects nor will the properties `paws` and `hair` be available to the old ones.

You want:

```
Dog.prototype.paws = 4;
Dog.prototype.hair = true;
```

---

You can try:

```
console.log(benji.__proto__ === rusty.__proto__); // prints true
console.log(lucy.__proto__ === rusty.__proto__); // prints false
```

and `console.dir(x.__proto__)` should show you the properties of the prototype objects (at least in Chrome).